# Configure http honeypot on my ubuntu server

Tags: honeypot

I want to configure an http honeypot on my ubuntu server. I am using apache web server. I am thinking to set 80 port for the honeypot and some other unusual port like 8978 or 6723 for my site. I will redirect my domain on this port using proxypass so users who access my site using domain will still be able to access the site and attackers will end on honeypot.

I could not find a guide to install http honeypot on ubuntu just like they have ssh honeypot. Can you please help?

I will manage to redirect my site on other port internally using proxypass  without opening that port for outside world. Will this approach help? or should I use nginx reverse proxy server to manage this. If there are any loopholes in this process, please comment and suggest me better way.

Thank You.

***EDITED***
I have found this site to install ssh honeypot on ubuntu server
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-kippo-an-ssh-honeypot-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server

Similar way I was finding to install it for http.
Please help.

Comment: Derek - wanting to setup a proxy/redirect is off topic here, and as Christian said, you aren't describing a honeypot at all. Have a look at the posts on Honeypots in the sidebar to the right.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confused about what a honeypot is [used for](https://www.sans.org/security-resources/idfaq/what-is-a-honeypot/1/9). The situation you described above isn't a honeypot at all, it's just a proxy that has non-standard configuration.

To set up an actual honeypot, you have a separate system (lacking some of your real defenses) that's supposed to be attacked and abused, thereby saving systems you care about from that treatment. So you can collect data on who/what/how is attacking you.

Comment: But I have a domain name and it needs to go on correct system always. How can I send attacker to false system and a real user to correct server.

Comment: @Derek you can't. You can **entice** the attackers with a honeypot, but there's no way to tell if a user is up to something malicious or if they're just a regular user without more information, which you can't glean from them simply navigating to your domain. You can setup a blacklist when you've seen some malicious activity, but what you're looking to do isn't possible without a way to ID malicious users, and with it being simple to spoof addresses you're stuck either way.

Answer (score -1):

not sure but i think you mean something like

if some one types in the browser the ip he lands on a "honeypot site" 
if some one types in mydomain.com he lands on a "honeypot site"

if some one types in secret.mydomain.com he gets the real content

you can do that with virtual hosts but i dont think it will be much of a protection